# Using Arabic letters in moderncv package

Tags: pdftex, moderncv, arabic

I'm trying to include a small snippet or Arabic script into my document. This works fine if I use the documentclass `article`, but I'm using the `moderncv` package as provided [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hurder/math589/vita.html), and for some reason, it won't play nice with any of the Arabic packages for LaTeX (that I know of). Note: my MacTeX distribution also packages a `moderncv` package, but I think it's different: they give slightly different results. In fact, my document, as it is, doesn't compile with this version of `moderncv`.

Anyway, I'm failing to include my piece of Arabic script. I've tried the following things:

- `\usepackage{polyglossia}`. But it requires XeLaTeX, and my document doesn't seem to want to compile with XeLaTeX (only with pdfLaTeX). I think there are some other XeLaTeX based solutions as well.
- `\usepackage{arabtex}` When I try to compile this, I get the following error, which I don't know how to resolve:

  ```
  ! Undefined control sequence
  <argument> \rm \it

  l.551 \settransfont {\rm \it }
                                % standard font for transliteration
  ```
- `\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[arabic]{babel}` This gives me the following error: `! LaTeX Error: \tableofcontents undefined.` This is actually easy enough to fix: `\newcommand{\tableofcontents}{}`. Rinse and repeat for a few other commands. Until, finally, I get this error message:

  ```
  ! Undefined control sequence.
  \thetable ...\number \c@table .\number \c@chapter 
                                                    }\protect \else \protect \...
  l.24 \section{Arabic}
  ```

  Again, I don't know how to resolve this.
- Finally, I try setting the font directly, like this:

  ```
  \usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
  ...
  {\usefont{LAE}{cmr}{m}{n}\selectfont العربية}
  ```

  This does give me Arabic letters in my document, but they will end op left-to-right, and they will be the isolated forms of the letters, instead of joined letters.

I don't mind if the solution is ugly, I just want it to work. It's only a few words in an otherwise completely English document.

Here's a minimal document with the `moderncv` package that will reproduce the problem (on my machine, at least).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{ABC}
\familyname{XYZ}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{A section}

(...a few words in Arabic here...)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`moderncv` doesn't provide support for the old two-letter commands such as `\rm`, `\it` and `arabtex` needs those commands, so one option would be to declare them *before* loading `arabtex`, and then use `\RL` to transliterate the Arabic text; a little example (I have no idea what the Arabic text says; I just copied it from elsewhere):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\makeatletter
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\makeatother
\usepackage{arabtex}

\firstname{ABC}
\familyname{XYZ}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{A section}
\RL{f.s.hY AltrA_t}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add `\usepackage[english]{babel}` to make it work with the version of `moderncv` I'm using, but it works now! Your Arabic text means something like 'classical heritage'.

Comment: @jqno Glad to hear it worked. Thanks for the translation of the text.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `xelatex` -- `arabtex` fonts are readable, but kind of amateurish.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{Libre Bodoni}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}




\firstname{ABC}
\familyname{XYZ}
\title{curriculum vitae}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{A section}
\textarabic{اسمي سليم}

\end{document}
```

> Yes, there are plenty of errors from `microtype`, but the document compiles in the end. I'd rather not play with `moderncv` internals, but it should be simple to remove those error messages.